# "Could not find task 'npm'" error in VS Code

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

Whenever I try to run a JavaScript or Python file in VS Code this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyRLn.png) appears:

I have tried reinstalling node but it still wont work. When I click on configure I am shown [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5wz0.png) options. When I click on any of them I am directed to this [json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HfWS.png).
I am pretty new to coding so sorry if I missed anything. Let me know if I did, I would be happy to provide it.

PS: I see that my interpreter at the bottom left is set to python, but clicking on it I am not getting any [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naaOG.png) that make sense to me. And also, this same thing happens when I try to run a python file.

Comment: How did you do to run the Javascript file? Did you use any command?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to run npm commands you should go to a directory that your nodejs is installed... if you want to run npm commands in other directories you should go to the directory that you want and then run cmd and type in the commant

```
set path=C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

then you can run all of the npm commands in your directory

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @FourierDecepticon your welcome... please accept my answer with clicking on the tick Icon :)

Comment: where should we add this path? In tasks.json file? If not, where? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't open the right directory (I was inside the project parent directory). Maybe it would help someone else who get into

Answer (score 0):

The list of commands you see in there are what is called VS Code tasks, see details here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

In your particular case they have been created to run `npm` commands from within VS Code without opening the terminal. These require a `package.json` file at the root of your project directory with corresponding script commands.

An example `package.json` file might look something like this:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "install": "npm install",
    "test": "node test.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

**WARNING: your project should have a `package.json` file with scripts that match what has been specified in your `tasks.json` file.**

Please provide a working copy of you application somewhere online, e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), if you require more help.